# Fill in values in other columns based on missing dates in another columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am currently having a similar need to the question in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978196/pandas-filling-missing-dates-and-values-within-group), but it looks like it cannot fill in the `dates` if the `min` and `max` dates of the given `date` column does not fall into the first and last day of a given month and year. In particular, assume this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c'], 'dt': ['2016-01-05','2016-01-08', '2016-01-10','2016-01-15','2016-01-16', '2016-01-22', '2016-01-19'], 'val': [1,33,2,1,5,5,6], 'price': [1,2,1,1,2,5.5,4.2]})

  user          dt  val  price
0    a  2016-01-05    1    1.0
1    a  2016-01-08   33    2.0
2    b  2016-01-10    2    1.0
3    b  2016-01-15    1    1.0
4    c  2016-01-16    5    2.0
5    c  2016-01-22    5    5.5
6    c  2016-01-19    6    4.2
```

Using the code in the first answer of the above thread, the resulting dataframe can only fill in `0` values for all `dates` between `2016-01-05` and `2016-01-22`. It could not do the same thing on dates between `2016-01-01` and `2016-01-04`, OR from `2016-01-23` to `2016-01-31.` I wonder if anyone could help address this point, as I currently have a need to accomplish the fill-in for every missing dates within a given month and year?

**Expected Output**

```
  user          dt  val  price
0    a  2016-01-01    0    0.0
1    a  2016-01-02    0    0.0
2    a  2016-01-03    0    0.0
3    a  2016-01-04    0    0.0
4    a  2016-01-05    1    1.0
5    a  2016-01-06    0    0.0
6    a  2016-01-07    0    0.0
7    a  2016-01-08   33    2.0
8    a  2016-01-09    0    0.0
9    a  2016-01-10    0    0.0
10   a  2016-01-11    0    0.0
11   a  2016-01-12    0    0.0
12   a  2016-01-13    0    0.0
13   a  2016-01-14    0    0.0
14   a  2016-01-15    0    0.0
15   a  2016-01-16    0    0.0
16   a  2016-01-17    0    0.0
17   a  2016-01-18    0    0.0
18   a  2016-01-19    0    0.0
19   a  2016-01-20    0    0.0
20   a  2016-01-21    0    0.0
21   a  2016-01-22    0    0.0
22   a  2016-01-23    0    0.0
23   a  2016-01-24    0    0.0
24   a  2016-01-25    0    0.0
25   a  2016-01-26    0    0.0
26   a  2016-01-27    0    0.0
27   a  2016-01-28    0    0.0
28   a  2016-01-29    0    0.0
29   a  2016-01-30    0    0.0
30   a  2016-01-31    0    0.0
31   b  2016-01-01    0    0.0
32   b  2016-01-02    0    0.0
33   b  2016-01-03    0    0.0
34   b  2016-01-04    0    0.0
35   b  2016-01-05    0    0.0
36   b  2016-01-06    0    0.0
37   b  2016-01-07    0    0.0
38   b  2016-01-08    0    0.0
39   b  2016-01-09    0    0.0
40   b  2016-01-10    2    1.0
41   b  2016-01-11    0    0.0
42   b  2016-01-12    0    0.0
43   b  2016-01-13    0    0.0
44   b  2016-01-14    0    0.0
45   b  2016-01-15    1    1.0
46   b  2016-01-16    0    0.0
47   b  2016-01-17    0    0.0
48   b  2016-01-18    0    0.0
49   b  2016-01-19    0    0.0
50   b  2016-01-20    0    0.0
51   b  2016-01-21    0    0.0
52   b  2016-01-22    0    0.0
53   b  2016-01-23    0    0.0
54   b  2016-01-24    0    0.0
55   b  2016-01-25    0    0.0
56   b  2016-01-26    0    0.0
57   b  2016-01-27    0    0.0
58   b  2016-01-28    0    0.0
59   b  2016-01-29    0    0.0
60   b  2016-01-30    0    0.0
61   b  2016-01-31    0    0.0
62   c  2016-01-01    0    0.0
63   c  2016-01-02    0    0.0
64   c  2016-01-03    0    0.0
65   c  2016-01-04    0    0.0
66   c  2016-01-05    0    0.0
67   c  2016-01-06    0    0.0
68   c  2016-01-07    0    0.0
69   c  2016-01-08    0    0.0
70   c  2016-01-09    0    0.0
71   c  2016-01-10    2    1.0
72   c  2016-01-11    0    0.0
73   c  2016-01-12    0    0.0
74   c  2016-01-13    0    0.0
75   c  2016-01-14    0    0.0
76   c  2016-01-15    1    1.0
77   c  2016-01-16    5    2.0
78   c  2016-01-17    0    0.0
79   c  2016-01-18    0    0.0
80   c  2016-01-19    6    4.2
81   c  2016-01-20    0    0.0
82   c  2016-01-21    0    0.0
83   c  2016-01-22    5    5.5
84   c  2016-01-23    0    0.0
85   c  2016-01-24    0    0.0
86   c  2016-01-25    0    0.0
87   c  2016-01-26    0    0.0
88   c  2016-01-27    0    0.0
89   c  2016-01-28    0    0.0
90   c  2016-01-29    0    0.0
91   c  2016-01-30    0    0.0
92   c  2016-01-31    0    0.0
```

Comment: Could you please add a desired output for that specific example to your question?

Comment: @Rabinzel It took me a while but I finished meeting your request. Apologize :)

Comment: To be more helpful, the given start date for each `user` might actually fall into this case for me. But I still need to fill in the remaining dates within a given year and month for each user. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68197914/python-fill-in-missing-dates-for-grouped-ids-where-each-id-has-its-own-min-and?rq=1

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: @Rabinzel Yes I did. It's very close but I think it still requires 1 more step to get a data-frame that does NOT have any level? Could you help add it to complete your answer, although I upvoted it.

Comment: good! ok, just added a `.reset_index()` at the end. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])

(df.set_index('dt')
   .groupby('user', as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.reindex(pd.date_range(d.index.min(), d.index.max()),
                              fill_value=0
                             ))
   .reset_index(-1)
)
```

If you want to round to month start/end:

```
(df.set_index('dt')
   .groupby('user', as_index=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.reindex(pd.date_range(d.index.min()-pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1),
                                            d.index.max()+pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)
                                           ).rename('id'),
                              fill_value=0)
                             )
   .reset_index('id')
)
```

Output:

```
           id user  val  price
0  2016-01-01    0    0    0.0
0  2016-01-02    0    0    0.0
0  2016-01-03    0    0    0.0
0  2016-01-04    0    0    0.0
0  2016-01-05    a    1    1.0
..        ...  ...  ...    ...
2  2016-01-27    0    0    0.0
2  2016-01-28    0    0    0.0
2  2016-01-29    0    0    0.0
2  2016-01-30    0    0    0.0
2  2016-01-31    0    0    0.0

[93 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want that (see link), because the new range can/ or will be outside the min/max value of the current data (at least that's how I understood it)

Comment: @Rabinzel then it's unclear

Comment: @Rabinzel: Yes, you are right on your interpretation.

Comment: @mozway What is unclear, could you clarify?

Comment: I added an alternative

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you just need to define your own [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), then build a new MultiIndex to get the daily data for each user and use [`pd.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html?highlight=reindex#pandas.DataFrame.reindex).

```
df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"])
df = df.set_index(["user", "dt"])

daily_idx = pd.date_range(start="2016-01-01", end="2016-01-31", freq="D")

new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df.index.get_level_values("user").unique(), daily_idx], names=["user", "daily"]
)
out = df.reindex(new_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print(out)
```

```
   user      daily  val  price
0     a 2016-01-01    0    0.0
1     a 2016-01-02    0    0.0
2     a 2016-01-03    0    0.0
3     a 2016-01-04    0    0.0
4     a 2016-01-05    1    1.0
5     a 2016-01-06    0    0.0
6     a 2016-01-07    0    0.0
7     a 2016-01-08   33    2.0
8     a 2016-01-09    0    0.0
9     a 2016-01-10    0    0.0
10    a 2016-01-11    0    0.0
11    a 2016-01-12    0    0.0
12    a 2016-01-13    0    0.0
13    a 2016-01-14    0    0.0
14    a 2016-01-15    0    0.0
15    a 2016-01-16    0    0.0
16    a 2016-01-17    0    0.0
17    a 2016-01-18    0    0.0
18    a 2016-01-19    0    0.0
19    a 2016-01-20    0    0.0
20    a 2016-01-21    0    0.0
21    a 2016-01-22    0    0.0
22    a 2016-01-23    0    0.0
23    a 2016-01-24    0    0.0
24    a 2016-01-25    0    0.0
25    a 2016-01-26    0    0.0
26    a 2016-01-27    0    0.0
27    a 2016-01-28    0    0.0
28    a 2016-01-29    0    0.0
29    a 2016-01-30    0    0.0
30    a 2016-01-31    0    0.0
31    b 2016-01-01    0    0.0
32    b 2016-01-02    0    0.0
33    b 2016-01-03    0    0.0
34    b 2016-01-04    0    0.0
35    b 2016-01-05    0    0.0
36    b 2016-01-06    0    0.0
37    b 2016-01-07    0    0.0
38    b 2016-01-08    0    0.0
39    b 2016-01-09    0    0.0
40    b 2016-01-10    2    1.0
41    b 2016-01-11    0    0.0
42    b 2016-01-12    0    0.0
43    b 2016-01-13    0    0.0
44    b 2016-01-14    0    0.0
45    b 2016-01-15    1    1.0
46    b 2016-01-16    0    0.0
47    b 2016-01-17    0    0.0
48    b 2016-01-18    0    0.0
49    b 2016-01-19    0    0.0
50    b 2016-01-20    0    0.0
51    b 2016-01-21    0    0.0
52    b 2016-01-22    0    0.0
53    b 2016-01-23    0    0.0
54    b 2016-01-24    0    0.0
55    b 2016-01-25    0    0.0
56    b 2016-01-26    0    0.0
57    b 2016-01-27    0    0.0
58    b 2016-01-28    0    0.0
59    b 2016-01-29    0    0.0
60    b 2016-01-30    0    0.0
61    b 2016-01-31    0    0.0
62    c 2016-01-01    0    0.0
63    c 2016-01-02    0    0.0
64    c 2016-01-03    0    0.0
65    c 2016-01-04    0    0.0
66    c 2016-01-05    0    0.0
67    c 2016-01-06    0    0.0
68    c 2016-01-07    0    0.0
69    c 2016-01-08    0    0.0
70    c 2016-01-09    0    0.0
71    c 2016-01-10    0    0.0
72    c 2016-01-11    0    0.0
73    c 2016-01-12    0    0.0
74    c 2016-01-13    0    0.0
75    c 2016-01-14    0    0.0
76    c 2016-01-15    0    0.0
77    c 2016-01-16    5    2.0
78    c 2016-01-17    0    0.0
79    c 2016-01-18    0    0.0
80    c 2016-01-19    6    4.2
81    c 2016-01-20    0    0.0
82    c 2016-01-21    0    0.0
83    c 2016-01-22    5    5.5
84    c 2016-01-23    0    0.0
85    c 2016-01-24    0    0.0
86    c 2016-01-25    0    0.0
87    c 2016-01-26    0    0.0
88    c 2016-01-27    0    0.0
89    c 2016-01-28    0    0.0
90    c 2016-01-29    0    0.0
91    c 2016-01-30    0    0.0
92    c 2016-01-31    0    0.0
```